# Using Citrix Viewer for Mac to view a virtual PC

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab, citrix-receiver, command-tab

I have a macbook pro, and the `Apple Command` key is on both sides of the spacebar, but the `control` key is on the left only.  My honest experience with using Citrix Viewer to view a PC is that it's basically a living hell for getting work done:

1. every time I AppleCommand-Tab back from my other programs to the VPC, the VPC thinks I just sent it a `Ctrl` key signal and it opens up the main windows menu
2. In windows, all of the shortcut keys like Save, Copy and Paste are `Ctrl-S`, `Ctrl-C`,`Ctrl-V` etc. instead of `AppleCommand-S`, `..C`, `..V` - so since for me the `control` key is only on the left, it's clumsy to have to move my right hand over to execute those commands
3. An added bonus, it would be nice to be able to `alt-tab` between programs while inside Citrix Receiver, but that doesn't work with my Alt(Option) key, and `AppleCommand-Tab` just means leave Citrix and go back to my other Mac programs.

Sorry to be long in describing but if anyone has an elegant solution to these 2-3 problems it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the keyboard preferences pane in my instance of Citrix Workspace:
[image: citrixReceiverScreenshot]

At least in a XenApp environment (which is what I have available), it works in the following way:

- Cmd+Tab switches between open applications on my local machine
- Alt ("Option")+Tab switches between open applications in my XenDesktop session
- Ctrl key combinations and Cmd key combinations can be used interchangeably
- Localization-specific characters that in Windows require the AltGr key can be typed either macOS natively or using Cmd+Alt+key.
- I summon the Start menu by pressing Ctrl+Esc.

Now that I think of it, I don't figure I ever use the right-side Cmd/Alt/Shift keys other than to emulate the AltGr key.

(Citrix Viewer, to my knowledge, is a deprecated product, and Workspace should be used in its place. Note, though, that especially for the Mac I've seen some issues with older XenApp versions not displaying the screen correctly, so back up your current config before changing anything!)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm stuck with Citrix Viewer for these current projects, but I will remember this fo when I have time to try a different project from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Citrix viewer is a nightmare to configure to behave like windows.

I was searching for solution for years until i found:

https://gist.github.com/jdleslie/9a3566037e35437a3846c428f306318f

You configure Citrix to use:

- Send Control using: Control
- Send Alt using: Command (left)
- Send Windows using Command (right) checkbox

Then in carabiner with rules from above link you do:

- Conversion of Tab to fn+Tab so that Cmd-Tab works as Alt-Tab in Citrix
- Conversion of Left Option to right Command so that all Windows key shortcuts work and Windows key is on normal location - between Ctrl and Alt

And finally everything works like it should have worked from the beginning by default.